# How to achieve phonegap application in android using senchatouch 2

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I've an example sencha touch2 application. It is working fine in my localhost browser(http://localhost/sencha/examples/navigationview/index.html).

Now i need to integrate this sencha applicaiton to android using phonegap 1.5.0.
i've downloaded phonegap libraries from [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/download-thankyou)

**phonegap-phonegap-1.5.0-0-gde1960d.zip** from phonegap website.
in that i've got cordova-1.5.0.js and cordova-1.5.0.jar file instead of phonegap. 
I've gone through with phonegap site got to know that cordova-1.5.0 and phonegap is same.

I've followed this [Get Started Guide](http://phonegap.com/start/#android)
In that they have not given how to integrate sencha touch2 MVC file architecture. The basic example in get started guide is working fine for me. 
My Problem is i couldnt able to integrate my sencha2 MVC file architecture. I've googled this but didnt get succeed. I'm doing any thing wrong here? Can you suggest me the right way to do this.
Thanks in Advance.

this is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ajax</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="development.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In app.js file i'm getting Error:

```
   //<debug>
    Ext.Loader.setPath({ // line no. 2
        'Ext': 'src'
    });
    //</debug>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean my "integrate my sencha2 MVC file architecture"? You are supposed to put any Web code you have into the `assets/www` folder of your Android project. You mentioned that the basic example in the get started guide is working, so what errors do you encounter in trying to run your project?

Comment: yes jayraj.Thanks for your reply.actually if you compare the file structure of senchatouch1.1(http://screencast.com/t/chDMwE7d13K) and senchatouch2.0(http://screencast.com/t/y9ykJLxi) is completely different. in senchatouch1.1 in index.html itself the total javascript code exists(you can directly add this index.html with supported files in andoid /assets/www/ it will work fine).senchatouch2.0 the folder structure is different in this you can find in model,view,controller and store folders in app folder. I couldnt able to understand how to add these files in android-phonegap assets/www folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ext.Loader` is what allows your JS files to live in different folders inside the `app` folder. Sencha Touch can dynamically load your files from the appropriate directory if you have configured `Ext.Loader` as described in the [tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/mvc_dependencies)

Then just put the `index.html` the `app` folder and everything else into `www` for Phonegap. It works just the same as a web page. To be completely explicit:

```
www
 |
 |-index.html
 |-app/
 |-css/
 |-whatever else
```

Comment: Jayraj thanks for your answer. It worked for me. now i'm getting this error. 04-09 17:15:42.722: E/Web Console(1675): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Ext at file:///android_asset/www/app.js:2
 do know why this error occuring.

Comment: You haven't included the Sencha Touch JS file (usually named `sencha-touch-debug-all.js` or something) anywhere in index.html. Please follow the tutorial precisely. And if you have new problems or issues, please create new questions instead of adding on to this one.

Answer (score 0):

For a production build you need to use the command line tool which gives you a single js file including all the MVC components and extras like API's or libs you need PLUS all the necessary EXT and sencha stuff stuff and no more.

Getting to that stage is quite an achievement and then you should have your index.html file ready to make into an APK.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use MDS applaud phone gap http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap%20Eclipse%20PlugIn%20for%20Android

for developing sencha 2 applications with phone gap .
It will give you a way to work with phonegap+sencha 
you can then add the path to ur sencha js and css file in the index.html and manually need to add the app folder.
the index would look like

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
   <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <title>PhoneGap Demo with Sencha Touch</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="sencha/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" type="text/css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="sencha/sencha-touch-all.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegapdemo-w-sencha.js">        </script>
  </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at phonegap-build. See my answers here on the forum about phonegap.
You get your sencha app running immediately on iphone, android, blackberry and everything else !!

You don't even need to use phonegap API calls!

You only have to make a copy of app.html into index.html.

If you DO want to use the phoneGap API, simply use it. No added files needed or anything else.
In the index.html you have to add the line

```
<script...  phonegap="cordova-1.0.7" />
```

or whatever version is then valid.

(This info is true as of June 11, 2012 -- I suppose when beta period is over it will cost)